# An error when SSH Tunneling on Linux. I get error of "...bad id: ...Received ieof for nonexistent channel"

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Whenever I open an SSH tunnel on linux with the ssh command after visiting a few sites over the proxy I get this:
channel_by_id: 3: bad id: channel free
Disconnecting: Received ieof for nonexistent channel 3.

On Windows the tunneling software I use just deals with channel closures and opens new ones when necessary. Is there a client or way I can do this on linux? I've found a program called autossh but every time it reconnects I end up needing to re-enter my password because it resets the entire connection not just the channel.

This is the output of ssh with -v

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <host> port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: no match: WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA key
debug1: Host '<host>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
User@host's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to <host>.
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 7: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 8: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 9: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 10: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 11: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 12: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 13: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 14: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 15: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 16: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 17: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 18: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 19: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 20: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 21: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 22: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 23: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 24: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 25: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 26: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 27: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 28: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 29: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 30: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 31: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 32: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 33: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 34: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 10: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for connect.facebook.net port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51036 to 127.0.0.1 port 1080, nchannels 35
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 10: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 11: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for connect.facebook.net port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51037 to 127.0.0.1 port 1080, nchannels 35
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 11: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 33: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for cdn.syndication.twitter.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51059 to 127.0.0.1 port 1080, nchannels 35
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 33: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 10 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: no sink for exit-status on channel 10
debug1: channel 10: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for webchat.freenode.net port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51061 to 127.0.0.1 port 1080, nchannels 35
channel_by_id: 10: bad id: channel free
Disconnecting: Received ieof for nonexistent channel 10.
```

Comment: it may help if you give the ssh command(s) you are using, also consider adding -v to any ssh client command

Comment: ssh -N Username@host -D 1080

Comment: I don't know really.. Have you tried a most up to  date ssh to rule out bugs? When you say Windows is OK, do you mean a linux client to a  Windows sshd server is ok?  or a windows ssh client to a linux sshd server is ok? (if you don't know the answer to those qs then try it and find out.. to help isolate whether it's the server or the client)

Comment: What I mean is I have a Windows client that works fine. It's called BitVise tunnelier. It works however putty doesn't. Putty gives me the same error that the linux SSH command does. Tunnelier on the other hand opens and closes channels frequently and gives a seamless connection and I'm looking for a linux client that does the same. It's going to a windows server BTW.

Comment: ok and what are you using for the windows ssh server?

Comment: It's called freesshd

Comment: and can you try making the connection with putty from the command line, and show the line you use? (though I know putty doesn't have many options from the command line, most options are done via a putty profile, but still the command line may be revealing). Also, try cygwin ssh client.

Comment: What do you mean from the command line? Does putty actually have a CLI interface?

Comment: Yes but the command line interface for putty is a bit limited. and in retrospect, won't tell you much e.g. putty from the command line you might do putty -load myprofile  and the settings are in that profile called myprofile. So you set the settings in the gui save them in a profile, then run the command that runs putty loading that profile.  Try cygwin ssh client too, that has a nice command line and uses openssh so would be interesting to see whether it works.

Comment: Sorry it took so long I needed to setup a windows VM because I'm in my dorm and don't have a windows machine but putty gave me: Disconnected: Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF for nonexistent channel 257. As far as cygwin is concerned does it come with a built in ssh command because it doesn't appear to.

Comment: Cygwin is amazing it has an enormous mouth-watering library of commands including ssh. Run the cygwin setup file and see this page of it http://xahlee.info/mswin/i/Cygwin_Setup_dialogue.png see openssh there, you can type ssh in the search and it comes up there too and you can maximize the screen and click 'view' and see all the commands cygwin can have, listed in different ways.

Comment: Cygwin gave me the exact same error as the linux ssh command did word for word.

Comment: you could edit into your question the output of your command with -v so `ssh -v -N Username@host -D 1080`  Also since I notice this question mentions something about 'tunnel via loopback' in his ssh client,  try something varying whether it binds to the loopback address or not, so  replacing 1080 with `*:1080` and try with  `127.0.0.1:1080`

Comment: also you could try the openssh mailing list and if they can answer it you could post the answer and any troubleshooting steps here here

Comment: There's my -v print out

Comment: and no difference whether *: or 127.0.0.1: ? Another thing you can look at is look at the connection in wireshark how the tunnel is made, and see if you can see any difference at the tcp/ip level, the levels shown in wireshark, that give a clue as to what is happening. Wireshark shows a lot, and can be clearer than ssh's error messages! And can give more food to google. Otherwise, I don't know.. but besides the openssh mailing list, you could try irc- freenode #openssh if you haven't already.

Comment: No the *: and 127.0.0.1: didn't make any difference at all. Also I think I mentioned it but maybe not but the windows client I use does still show the channels being closed in it's log it just doesn't kill the connection when it happens. I'll also go talk to the openssh team and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the server I was using was violating the SSH protocol and by simply changing server software it fixed it.

**ADDED BY BARLOP**(from OP's comments- The server software was freesshd)

Comment: and what server software was that?  btw you might've seen indications of that with wireshark.

Comment: The server software causing the problem was FreeSSHd

Comment: IMHO the more important question would be: What server software did you change to?

Comment: what is an `ioef` packet

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I turned on developer mode on Windows 10 which started Windows native SSH server instead of OpenSSH which was the intended server. In general, check the ssh daemon you are trying to log into.